# cordova create project failed,but it can run or build

Tags: node.js, cordova

I tried to reinstall the cordova and reinstall the system, but it didn't work.My cordova version is 7.0.1,node version is v6.10.3 and npm version is 3.10.10.The code for the new project error is as follows.

```
 - E:\cordovaProject>cordova create myapp  com.mu myapp -d  Using
   detached cordova-create  Creating a new cordova project.  Copying
   assets."  Using cordova-fetch for
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
   cordova\node_modules\_cordova-app-hello-world@3.12.0@cordova-app-hello-world\ind
   ex.js  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"
   install C:\Users\
   Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\_cordova-app
   -hello-world@3.12.0@cordova-app-hello-world\index.js"" Command finished with error code 4294963238: cmd /s /c ""C:\Program
   Files\nodejs \npm.cmd" install
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordov
   a\node_modules\_cordova-app-hello-world@3.12.0@cordova-app-hello-world\index.js"

   Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (  Error from Cordova
   Fetch: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963238 Error
   output: npm ERR! not a package
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
   ordova\node_modules\_cordova-app-hello-world@3.12.0@cordova-app-hello-world\inde x.js npm ERR! addLocal Could not install
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
   ode_modules\cordova\node_modules\_cordova-app-hello-world@3.12.0@cordova-app-hel
   lo-world\index.js npm ERR! path
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8056-980eaa3d\unpack
   -8e52606f\package.json npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
   open 'C:\Users\Administrator\
   AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8056-980eaa3d\unpack-8e52606f\package.json'
   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
   ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
   ERR! enoent

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-18T0
   2_13_23_845Z-debug.log)
```

Comment: explain your problem and what fixes you did try? what version of node and other environment you are using ?

Comment: It fails only when it is created, but it can run or build.I tried to reinstall the cordova and reinstall the system, but it didn't work.My cordova  version is 7.0.1,node version is v6.10.3 and npm version is 3.10.10

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall Cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I had the same issue as you described above. 
And I solved the issue with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683408/3989719).

Comment: please include answer in the text

Comment: my solution:1,uninstall cordova .use hand or  command line(inclue the file of npm-cache)2，reinstall the npm  not use proxy

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Windows when i try add plugin. To resolve, delete the node_modules and retry the command to add the plugin. This resolve my problem.

Comment: UPDATE

To resolve for all others problems with this same code error do this:

- find the path /nodejs in Program Files and give all security permissions for the user Everyone;

- when add plugin do the project, add --nofetch in the end of command;

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file `C:\Users\YOUR-PC-USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-create\node_modules\cordova-fetch\index.js`
2. Find text `fetchArgs.push(target);`, then insert the following code before this line:

   ```
   if(fs.existsSync(target) && fs.statSync(target).isFile()){
       target = require(target).dirname
   }
   ```

Package version list:

1. cordova: 8.1.2
2. cordova-app-hello-world: 3.12.0
3. cordova-create: 1.1.2
4. cordova-fetch: 1.3.1

This works for me.